# wsimport -clientjar generates classes in (default package)

Tags: java, web-services, jar, wsimport

I'm using the -clientjar wsimport parameter to export my WebService into a jar.

```
>wsimport -d C:\webservice -keep -clientjar webservice.jar http://localhost:8080/WebService?wsdl
```

A folder with the source code (.java files) and a webservice.jar are created.

The jar looks like this:

```
com
  |
  company
        |
        webservice
                 |
                 a bunch of .class files

META-INF
       |
       wsdl
          |
          wsdl file
```

However, when I put it on the WEB-INF/lib folder in my project, the classes are in the *(default package)* and are named like

```
com\company\webservice\file.class
```

I can't understand why. I've also used the -p parameter to specify a package name but it doesn't work.

Any clues?

Comment: same here. any clues?

Comment: when I use the `-clientjar` option the jar generated as a result of that contains **only** a META-INF folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options of achieving this , both works like a charm.
And both options can be automated from ant\gradle you name it .

1.To use -clientjar and then to repack the sources

2.Manually insert the wsdl into jar and customize the wsdLlocation URL

Assuming you have C:\WSDL\SO\stas.wsdl 
(I was running on windows)

```
CD  C:\WSDL\SO\
```

**First option**

```
C:\WSDL\SO>wsimport -clientjar StasWebServiceClient.jar stas.wsdl
```

This creates  StasWebServiceClient.jar jar file , but when importing it to eclipse, the sources are not importable , because of the topic problem (default package).

=> Unzip the jar file to current folder  , you can use 7zip, or any other great zip tool , or you can run

```
C:\WSDL\SO>jar xf StasWebServiceClient.jar
```

to unzip the jar .

Folder hierarchy should look like

```
C:\WSDL\SO\META-INF

C:\WSDL\SO\stas.wsdl(original wsdl)

C:\WSDL\SO\StasWebServiceClient.jar(generated jar file)

C:\WSDL\SO\META-INF\wsdl(created by -clientjar)

C:\WSDL\SO\META-INF\wsdl\stas.wsdl(copied by -clientjar)

C:\WSDL\SO\com\...

/* all generated classes\sources */

C:\WSDL\SO\com\...
```

=> Do

```
C:\WSDL\SO>jar -cvf StasWebServiceClientCorrect.jar com META-INF
```

this will create another jar , StasWebServiceClientCorrect.jar , which now has the correct packaging .

**Second option**

=> Run wsimport

```
C:\WSDL\SO>wsimport -keep stas.wsdl
```

to generate the code .I always like to have -keep option there , but it's up to you.

=> create META-INF folder

```
C:\WSDL\SO>mkdir META-INF
```

=> Create META-INF/wsdl folder

```
C:\WSDL\SO>cd META-INF




C:\WSDL\SO\META-INF>mkdir wsdl
```

=> go one folder up .

```
C:\WSDL\SO\META-INF>cd ..
```

=> Copy stas.wsdl file into META-INF\wsdl\stas.wsdl

```
C:\WSDL\SO>copy stas.wsdl META-INF\wsdl\stas.wsdl
```

=> Create a jar archive

```
C:\WSDL\SO>jar -cvf StasWebServiceClient.jar com META-INF
```

Import the jar to workspace.
When you will be creating the actual call to the service , use :

```
StasService stasService = new  StasService(StasService.class.getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/wsdl/stas.wsdl") )
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is that `-clientjar` option is meant for an entirely different purpose than the OP expects.

The purpose of the `-clientjar` option is to embed a copy of the WSDL inside the generated artifacts so that it can become part of the application's jar file.  The benefit of having a bundled WSDL (and actually using it of course) is that the web service consumer does not have to make a call to the endpoint to download the WSDL every time it initiates itself.

Links:

https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2010/09/03/wsimport-clientjar-option-ease-client-side-web-service-progra

[Using jaxws-maven-plugin with -clientjar option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115342/using-jaxws-maven-plugin-with-clientjar-option)

Comment: The problem with this is that I found I need to modify the code generated by wsimport because it does not generate a working SOAP call without a small modification.  If I modify the source and recompile with Eclipse, it wipes out the met-inf folder with the wsdl file in it. 
 I have not yet found why wsimport.exe doesn't generate working code from the wsdl file that the website publishes.  I need to add an annotated "action" parameter to the IELDSubmissionService.submit() method with header attribute set to "true", and it then works.  But I have not found an elegant way to build this.

Comment: @sb4. Maybe post your question as a new question on SO ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Finally decided not to use the -clientjar option and generated a jar manually with jar.exe and works.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Unzip/unjar clientjar

2.) jar file using

```
jar cvf <jarName>.jar <root_folders>
```

example:

```
jar cvf weather.jar com META_INF
```

Answer (score 0):

I used -clientjar so it will do all the work for me, but used my favorite file archiver to unzjar and jar it again.