# Using jaxws-maven-plugin with -clientjar option

Tags: java, maven, wsimport

I'm using [jaxws-maven-plugin](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) to execute wsimport for a web service consumer app. I'm using the `-clientjar` option on wsimport which was introduced with JAX-WS 2.2.2 RI in 2010. I do this because I want to bundle the WSDL within the jar.

I don't have a problem crafting the pom. For plugin configuration I do something like:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <args>
        <arg>-clientjar</arg>
        <arg>bundled-wsdl.jar</arg>
    </args>
</configuration>
```

When I execute a build my created jar, lets call it `myapp.jar`, has file `bundled-wsdl.jar` within it. Inside the `bundled-wsdl.jar`'s META-INF directory I find the wsdl and xsd just as I like them. I'm also quite happy with the generated java code that come as a result of using the `-clientjar` option. So far so good.

But this stuff should be in `myapp.jar`'s META-INF, right?
The fact that it sits within `bundled-wsdl.jar`'s META-INF doesn't help me a lot.

The funny thing is that I do in fact get a wsdl file in `myapp.jar`'s META-INF which makes the application actually work. How it gets there I don't know. Also the xsd file isn't there, only in `bundled-wsdl.jar`'s META-INF.

The basic question is how to correctly use wsimport `-clientjar` option in a Maven project ?

Java 1.7.0_45.

Comment: https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/
Use this URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-clientjar` option is really poorly documented, IMHO.
Here's how I believe it works:

When the `-clientjar <jarfile>` option is used **three** things are happening:

1. You'll get a `<jarfile>` generated in the directory pointed to by
   the `-d` argument to the `wsimport` tool. This will contain within
   it both WSDL and any relevant XSD files as well. This little bundle will not be used for anything at all. If you want to make use of it it would be entirely up to you. But before you do see (2) below. I'm not sure what to use this jarfile for other than as a form of documentation.
2. You'll get a copy of the WSDL put into a file called
   `META-INF/wsdl/<svcname>.wsdl`. The generated classes will use this
   file in the no-arg proxy constructor. So this is what will actually
   be used if you request a bundled WSDL file with the `-clientjar`
   option.
3. The generated code will change so that `wsdlLocation`, if you are using the default no-arg constructor on the `@WebServiceClient` class, will be that of the bundled WSDL (from (2)), rather than the remote WSDL. Indeed if you use `-wsdllocation` on your command line together with `-clientjar` then whatever you specify with `-wsdllocation` will have no effect as `-clientjar` will take precedence.

So we must focus on (2) and (3) because that's the only one being actually used ... at least if you use the generated code as-is.

It is interesting to note that the result of (2) is *only* a WSDL file. This file may have embedded links to XSD files but as far as I can tell such link will never be followed. The reason is that when we say a web service consumer needs the WSDL at runtime it really only needs the WSDL itself, at not the schema. The schema is "hardcoded" into the consumer and there's no way of changing it at runtime. Hence there's no reason to read schema information at runtime. (THIS IS FROM MY UNDERSTANDING)

Second thing to note about the WSDL that's included with (2): It is really just a copy of the original WSDL so it may not have endpoint you want. Actually in most cases it won't. This means that in this situation you'll need to set the endpoint yourself :

```java
// Use no-arg constructor. Means it uses the WSDL bundled into the 
// META-INF/wsdl directory rather than trying to retrieve WSDL over the
// network.
service = new HelloSvc_Service();
hello = service.getHelloSvcPort();

// Since we're using a bundled WSDL the web service URL cannot 
// be derived from that (it would be wrong!). So we have to set
// it explicitly.
((BindingProvider) hello).getRequestContext().put(
                BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                "http://myhellowebservice-address");
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for this plugin is a joke. A workaround is to manually extract the contents from the client jar after it is created like follows:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!--
                Generates JAXWS classes for all of the WSDL files in $[project.base.dir}/src/wsdl.
            -->
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-clientjar</arg>
                            <arg>${project.build.directory}/wsimport-client.jar</arg>
                        </args>
                        <wsdlUrls>
                            <wsdlUrl>https://webservice.com/service.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                        </wsdlUrls>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <target>2.1</target>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!--
                Unjar the wsimport-client.jar created in the jaxws-maven-plugin to the WAR's classes folder
            -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/wsimport-client.jar" dest="${project.build.directory}/classes" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

taken from here: https://gist.github.com/mpellegrini/5439304

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I had to unzip the created jars and re-zip in one single jar (so, putting the wsdl file from the inner jar in the final jar).
Thanks to peterh comment, I think I understood the "trick": in Maven output I can see a log like

> `jaxws:wsimport args: [..., -Xnocompile, -clientjar wsdl.jar, ...]`

so the `wsimport` command is launched **without** compiling che code, and in fact a `wsdl.jar` is created in the `target/classes` folder.
I think `wsimport` is just generating the sources and the jar with the wsdl, then the compilation and the packaging is done in the following steps.